# PyCharm не устанавливается пакет mysqlclient

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

Установлена Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) PyCharm Community 2019.2.

Мне предоставили директорию с проектом, при попытке открыть файл **init**.py Появился запрос на список с обновлением модулей. Я согласился, все обновились успешно, кроме одного: mysqlclient

Пишется предложение установить модуль, я соглашаюсь нажав install requirements: `Packge requirement 'mysqlclient=1.4.2.post1' is not satisfied`

В окне ошибки следующая информация:

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1

error: MySQLdb/_mysql.c:37:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    Output:
Collecting mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: started
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /home/it/PycharmProjects/tiq_tests/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-zzdq5i0d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/it/PycharmProjects/tiq_tests/venv/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/it/PycharmProjects/tiq_tests/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:37:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------

Command "/home/it/PycharmProjects/tiq_tests/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-zzdq5i0d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/it/PycharmProjects/tiq_tests/venv/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/mysqlclient/
```

Хотя отдельно этот модуль установлен:

```
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1
```

Comment: Какая версия python

Comment: Версия питона: Python 3.6.8

Comment: Попробуйте как написано в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev` в консоли pycharm. После этого обычную команду установки
`pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: Спасибо, так ошибки нет. Будет репутация больше 15 отмечу галочкой )

Comment: Советую установливать как написано в PyPi там все указано чаще всего и у вас репутация уже 19

Comment: @Igor-Potapov 15 репутации нужно для голоса "за". Для отметки галочкой нет ограничения по репутации (возможно есть ограничение по времени, точно не знаю, вам должно написать если вы попробуете поставить галку).

Comment: Нет ) сегодня пришел на работу, PiCharm ошибку при инициализации не выдаёт, но при запуске скрипта пишет: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'` и в списке модулей `mysqlclient` и `MySQLdb` нет. При попытке установить пишется ошибка: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for mysqlclient`

Comment: Вы точно выбрали именно ту версию?